How do I pre-populate a Caldera form that is integrated with the Form Processor extension to present custom field data?
I'm using the Form Processor extension along with Caldera forms and the integration plugin on a Civi/WP site. I want to pass a contact ID and a checksum into the Caldera form via the URL, and have the form pre-populate with the available data about the contact. Many of these fields in the form are from a custom field set.
I've been reading through this helpful post and the linked replies on the CiviCRM Mattermost, which I think has got me part-way to a solution. But using the approach outlined there I don't seem to be able to set the default values for the custom fields in my form.
In the 'Retrieval of defaults' tab for my form processor I have set contact ID and checksum as my retrieval criteria, and used 'Contact: Get by ID' as the retrieval method, which makes sense to me. Then it looks like I need to map the input fields in my form processor with retrieved values. However I can't see the individual custom fields that I need in the available Actions. All I can see that seems helpful from the available options in the 'Values' drop-down is the custom fieldset.
It feels like I might need to add second retrieval method, but I'm at a loss.
If there's any decent documentation on this with some examples that would be super-helpful (I've so far only been able to find the chat posts), and I'd be more than happy to add to that o nce I've worked out how Form Processor is supposed to do its thing.

The reason I couldn't get access to my custom fields in this case was because the fields were in a custom field group that was defined as being for 'Organization' records. It looks like the Action Provider extension (at least as at version 1.141) isn't able to access custom fields for a contact where the custom fields are assigned to a specific contact type rather than being assigned for all Contacts. I was able to work round this limitation be changing the field group definition in the database from 'Organisation' to 'Contact' based on the advice given in How should I move a custom field to a different custom fieldset?
